# Passing array to function in C++ changes it's value without me performing any change inside the function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm having a very weird problem with a C++ array. Everything is well with it until I pass it to a function to write it onto disk, after that, the array is changed without me performing any operation of it.

```
    int saveMatrix(Long64_t*, unsigned int, const char*);

    void resetArray(Long64_t* array, unsigned int size)
    {
        for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            array[i] = 0;
    }

    int saveMatrix(Long64_t* array, unsigned int size, const char* filename)
    {
        // Returns:
        //  0 - Exit
        //  1 - Error

        ofstream out(filename, ios::out);
        if (!out) {
            cout << "Cannot open file.";
            return 1;
        }

        for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            out << array[i] << " ";
        }

        out.close();

        return 0;
    }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        cout << "The program needs the name of the ROOT file to analyse." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return gf_partial(argv[1]);
}
#endif

#include "../include/ROOT_Tree.hh"
#include "jbmArray.hh"

int gf_partial(const char* name) {
    // init macro
    gROOT->Reset();

    unsigned long int i, j;

    const unsigned int DetectorNumber = 4;
    /* Detectors are:
     0 lefs60Foil
     1 lefs60Fl
     2 lefs60Ml
     3 lefs150Foil
     4 lefs150F
     5 lefs150M
     6 ca60D
     7 ca60C
     8 ca60B
    */
    const double sourceRadius = 20.; // LAN2B In cm
    // const double sourceRadius = 11.; // LAN2A In cm
    const Int_t numberOfChannels = 4;
    // Float_t energyChannels[numberOfChannels] = {52., 85., 141., 227.}; // LAN2A F electron
    Float_t energyChannels[numberOfChannels] = {51., 80., 135., 218.}; // LAN2B F electron
    // Float_t energyChannels[numberOfChannels] = {42., 55., 130., 220.}; // LAN2B B electron
    // Float_t energyChannels[numberOfChannels] = {66., 101., 167., 269., 447., 798., 1391., 2926.}; // LAN2B M proton
    const Int_t numberOfDetectors = 9;
    Float_t energyChannelsError[numberOfChannels] = {0., 0., 0., 0.};
    // Float_t energyChannelsError[numberOfChannels] = {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.};

    Float_t vGeometryFactors[numberOfChannels];
    Float_t vError[numberOfChannels]; // the error amount
    Float_t vRealError[numberOfChannels]; // the calculated error

    Long64_t nHitsInDetector[numberOfChannels];
    resetArray(nHitsInDetector, numberOfChannels);

    Long64_t nHitsInDetectorNoSecondaries[numberOfChannels];
    resetArray(nHitsInDetectorNoSecondaries, numberOfChannels);

    double nEmitedParticlesPerChannel[numberOfChannels];
    resetArray(nEmitedParticlesPerChannel, numberOfChannels);

    //exclusiongraph()->Update();

    if (!TClassTable::GetDict("Event")) {
        gSystem->Load("../lib/libROOT_Tree.so");
    }

    // read the tree file generated in GEANT4
    TFile* treeFile = new TFile(name);
    treeFile->ls();
    TTree *myTree = (TTree*) treeFile->Get("hiscaleSim");

    // Create pointer to an event object for reading the branch values.
    Event* myEvent = new Event();
    TBranch* bEvent = myTree->GetBranch("EventBranch");
    bEvent->SetAddress(&myEvent);

    TClonesArray* hits = myEvent->GetHits();
    Hit* myHit;

    unsigned long int nEvents = myTree->GetEntries();
    cout << endl << "Number of Total Events = " << nEvents << endl << endl;

    Float_t sourceEnergy = 0.0;
    Float_t depositedEnergy = 0.0;
    Float_t sourceTime = 0.0;
    UInt_t parentID = 0;
    UInt_t trackID = 0;

    std::vector<float> fSourcePosition(3);
    std::vector<float> minSourcePosition(3);
    std::vector<float> maxSourcePosition(3);

    std::vector<float> fSourceMomentumDirection(3);
    std::vector<float> minSourceMomentumDirection(3);
    std::vector<float> maxSourceMomentumDirection(3);

    std::vector<float> totalDepositedEnergy(numberOfDetectors);
    //std::vector<unsigned long int> nHitsInDetector(numberOfDetectors);

    // std::vector<unsigned long int> nHitsInDetectorNoSecondaries(numberOfChannels);

    Float_t fParticlePDGMass = 0.0;
    Float_t fParticlePDGCharge = 0.0;
    //fParticleAtomicNumber = 0;
    //fParticleAtomicMass = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < nEvents; i++) {
        myTree->GetEntry(i);

        depositedEnergy = 0;
        sourceEnergy = myEvent->GetSourceEnergy();
        for (j = 0; j < myEvent->GetNHit(); j++) {
            myHit = (Hit*)hits->UncheckedAt(j);
            if (myHit->GetDetectorN() == DetectorNumber)
                depositedEnergy = myHit->GetTotalDepositedEnergy();
        }

        parentID = myEvent->GetParentID();
        trackID = myEvent->GetTrackID();

        for (j = 0; j < numberOfChannels; j++) {
            if (sourceEnergy == energyChannels[j]) {
                nEmitedParticlesPerChannel[j]++;
                if (depositedEnergy != 0) {
                    if (parentID == 0)
                        nHitsInDetectorNoSecondaries[j]++;
                    nHitsInDetector[j]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    char strnHitsInDetector[80];
    strcpy (strnHitsInDetector, name);
    strcat (strnHitsInDetector, ".nHitsInDetector");
    saveMatrix(nHitsInDetector, numberOfChannels, strnHitsInDetector);

    //char strnHitsInDetector[80];
    strcpy (strnHitsInDetector, name);
    strcat (strnHitsInDetector, ".nHitsInDetectorNoSecondaries");
    saveMatrix(nHitsInDetectorNoSecondaries, numberOfChannels, strnHitsInDetector);

    char strnEmitedParticlesPerChannel[80];
    strcpy (strnEmitedParticlesPerChannel, name);
    strcat (strnEmitedParticlesPerChannel, ".nEmitedParticlesPerChannel");
    saveMatrix(nEmitedParticlesPerChannel, numberOfChannels, strnEmitedParticlesPerChannel);

// from now on nEmitedParticlesPerChannel changes it's value and it's not ok anymore.
```

Comment: Almost certain the error lies elsewhere. Change your signature to `Long64_t const *`.

Comment: This code looks fine.  Since you're only showing us a small fragment of it, I'm fairly sure that the real error is elsewhere.

Comment: @templatetypedef Well, I've put the all code now, although I believe that the only points where I touched that value was in the places I had before.

Comment: What changes in the array? Have you tested your saveMatrix function with a simple known array, say containing one value?

Comment: @AndrewMorton It changes to completely disparate random values. I was trying to save and array: [20000, 0, 0, 0], it comes out something like: [7810202127646675044, 7018934177862021989, 1818586734, 0]. But worst, when it enters the saveMatrix function, the values are already completely random, even before I save it to the file, but if I output it right before calling the savingFunction, than it's all right.

Answer (score 7):

I think the issue is in these lines of code:

```
const Int_t numberOfChannels = 2;

Long64_t nEmitedParticlesPerChannel[numberOfChannels];
resetArray(nEmitedParticlesPerChannel, numberOfChannels);

nEmitedParticlesPerChannel[1] = 10;
nEmitedParticlesPerChannel[2] = 20;
```

Notice that you've sized the array `nEmittedParticlesPerChannel` to have two elements in it, but then write to indices 1 and 2.  Since C++ arrays are zero-indexed, this means that you are writing off the end of the array and clobbering whatever values in memory happen to be right after it.  This might destroy the contents of the array you passed in as a parameter, since this results in undefined behavior.

To fix this, try rewriting the last two lines as

```
nEmitedParticlesPerChannel[0] = 10;
nEmitedParticlesPerChannel[1] = 20;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, sorry, that was just an error when giving the example, in the original file it's correct.

Comment: @jbssm- To avoid errors like this in the future, please just copy and paste the code.  Also, can we see the code for `resetArray`?

Comment: I added the "resetArray" code as well. I didn't put the all code because it's quite big.